# Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided when I did yarn start

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig, react-typescript

**I did**

- I did yarn start and `http://localhost:3000/` was a success but a lot of problems
  have appeared

$ `yarn start`  also  `npm run start`
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-scripts start

```
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.jsx must be react-jsx (to support the new JSX transform in React 17)

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.56.1/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\taiga\Github\Typescript\eslint-app\example\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
Compiled successfully!

You can now view example in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.56.1:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

#### error

- `Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided`
- `Module './App' was resolved to 'c:/Users/taiga/Github/Typescript/eslint-app/example/src/App.tsx', but '--jsx' is not set.`
- `Argument for '--jsx' option must be: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'.`

#### I try

[I tried this one](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10129)

this is [my repo](https://github.com/taiga-programming/example-typescript)

**my goal**

- Using lint a `react-typescript-app`

Answer (score 2):

- Does it compile/work correctly right after initializing the project with CRA (create react app) ?

It might be the packages you have updated, try to compile it without updating any package after initializing with CRA. (https://github.com/taiga-programming/example-typescript/commit/b7074af02df6ce469b867a69625d5c1de7a209eb)

But first, there is something suspect in tsconfig.json in your commit https://github.com/taiga-programming/example-typescript/commit/88ee7bfb164d9017883ea91535fadeb7e17691aa:

```
   - "jsx": "react-jsx"
   + "jsx": "react"
```

Try to put `"jsx": "react-jsx"` back.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue with create-react-app (CRA) script. The only solution that works for me is adding the below config in `.env` file (in project root).

```
DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true
```